# React routing to endpoint but not rendering content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I can route to another endpoint, but the component content only appears on manual refresh.

I've seen this question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44356360/react-router-work-on-reload-but-not-when-clicking-on-a-link), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815174/react-router-dom-only-works-on-reload), and I've been checking out the [reactrouter docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter), amongst others. The solution always seems to be "add `withRouter`" or "make sure you're wrapping it in `Router`. I've done those things, but sadly got no where.

Here's the code:

**App.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div className="App">
          <NavBar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Provider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

**NavBar.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

function NavBar() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="navbar">
        <h3>Connectory</h3>
        <div className="buttons-container">
          <Link>
            <button>Settings</button>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/account"> // successfully redirects to /account, but doesn't render Account page content until refresh
            <button>Account</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default withRouter(NavBar);
```

EDIT: After comment suggestions, [here's a code sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-paper-3jmcb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) and here;s the **Account.js** page:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Account() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>This is the Account page</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: your code seems ok, try to create a code sandbox demo so we could see the whole picture

Comment: Could you please add the code for Account so that we can check if it is correct ?

Comment: @TaghiKhavari [here you go](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-paper-3jmcb?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: @letibelim added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem here is that, in your `Navbar.js`, you are re-setting your Routes again when they are already set in `App.js`.

```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/account" component={Account} /> // Route for Applicatin set here
  </Switch>
```

You do not need to do that again in. Check here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-germain-7fyry?file=/src/Navbar.js

Your Nabar should look like:

```
function NavBar() {
  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <h3>Connectory</h3>
      <div className="buttons-container">
        <Link to="/">
          <button>Settings</button>
        </Link>
        <Link to="/account">
          <button>Account</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks, this solved it. I'm pretty sure I tried that before and got an error that said "You can't use `Link` outside of `Router`", but maybe at that point I'd wrapped the main App component incorrectly.

Comment: This is programming, things does break and then we fix them :-) . By the way from `React-router-dom-5` onwards, the things have changed a bit ( Making use of Hooks, and Route setting is a bit different and more performant now). Do have a look , you will enjoy that :-)  https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start CHEERS

Answer (score 1):

Hi i found a bug in your code and that's the reason because is not working.

in this component you are injecting the Router to the rest of the app.

```
    function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

in this one you are injecting again the Router. That's why is not working you just have to remove the Router from de Navbar and it will work properly.

```
    function NavBar() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="navbar">
        <h3>Connectory</h3>
        <div className="buttons-container">
          <Link>
            <button>Settings</button>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/account">
            <button>Account</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

like this

```
 function NavBar() {
  return (
      <div className="navbar">
        <h3>Connectory</h3>
        <div className="buttons-container">
          <Link>
            <button>Settings</button>
          </Link>
          <Link to="/account">
            <button>Account</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Imran shared a similar solution above and you are indeed correct, that's the solution!